# Storing external API key in AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, passwords, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have the problem with storing external API (from which I am fetching some data on my Spring Boot application) private key on AWS. It is stored as elastic beanstalk environment property there. I tested locally the below code and it works however when I use test env (AWS) the property is loaded correctly, however I am getting an error:

```
Illegal base64 character a at a
```

Private key is just:

```
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
(...)
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Whenever I load this from file or as a spring property it works very well. But when it is on AWS loaded as env variable I am getting mentioned error.

```
@Component
@Slf4j
public class SfKeyLoaderImpl implements SfKeyLoader {

  @Value("${access-token-params.private-key}")
  private String privateKeyString;

  @Override
  public PrivateKey loadKey() {

    PrivateKey privateKey = null;

    try {
      String formattedKey = privateKeyString
          .replaceAll("\r\n", "")
          .replace("-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----", "")
          .replace("-----END PRIVATE KEY-----", "")
          .replaceAll(" ", "");
      KeyFactory factory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
      PKCS8EncodedKeySpec privSpec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(Base64.getDecoder().decode(formattedKey));
      privateKey = factory.generatePrivate(privSpec);

    } catch (Exception ex) {
      log.error("Error while loading key for salesforce jwt generation", ex);
    }

    return privateKey;
  }
}
```

The part of the code throwing an error:

```
  PKCS8EncodedKeySpec privSpec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(Base64.getDecoder().decode(formattedKey));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After two days we found that .replaceAll("\r\n", "") was enough on Windows, we had a problem because on Linux also .replaceAll("\n", "") should be added to process of the private key stored on AWS.